# Streaming Pattern Matching using Regex

Tags: java, regex, warc

I'd want to parse a large text file formatted in Warc version 0.9. A sample of such text is [here](http://chato.cl/webspam/datasets/uk2007/contents/excerpt.txt). If you take a look at it, you'll find the whole document consists of a list of following entries.

```
[Warc Headers]

[HTTP Headers]

[HTML Content]
```

I need to extract URL and HTML content from each entry (please note that the sample file consists of *multiple* page entries each of which is formatted like the content above.)

I used the following regular expression in Java:

```
Pattern.compile("warc/0\\.9\\s\\d+\\sresponse\\s(\\S+)\\s.*\n\n.*\n\n(.*)\n\n", Pattern.DOTALL)
```

Where group 1 and 2 represents the URL and the HTML content respectively. There's two problem with this code:

1. It's very slow to find a match.
2. Only matches with the first page.

Java Codes:

```
if(mStreamScanner.findWithinHorizon(PAGE_ENTRY, 0) == null){
    return null;
} else {
    MatchResult result = mStreamScanner.match();
    return new WarcPageEntry(result.group(1), result.group(2));
}
```

**Questions:**

- Why is my code only parsing the first page entry?
- Is there a faster way to parse a large text in a streaming manner?

Comment: Changing `.*` to `.*?` may boost performance, because it'll cause less backtracking, and it may even be more appropriate for your use.

Comment: @Andreas Thanks, It's now faster but only extracts the two first entries.

Comment: Have you considered using HTML parsers?

Comment: @anubhava Yes, I'm using Jsoup.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't tackle these huge HTML strings with a regex. How about relying on the structure of the document, instead?

E.g. like so:

```
HashMap<String, String> output = new HashMap<>();
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^warc\\/0\\.9\\s\\d+\\sresponse\\s(\\S+)\\s.*");

try (InputStreamReader is = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("excerpt.txt"), "UTF-8")) {               
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(is)) {      
        String line;        
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);

            if (matcher.matches()) {
                entityLoop: while (true) {
                    String url = matcher.group(1);

                    // skip header
                    int countEmptyLines = 0;
                    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        if ("".equals(line)) {
                            countEmptyLines++;
                            if (countEmptyLines == 2) break;
                        }
                    }

                    // extract HTML
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
                        if (matcher.matches()) { 
                            // got all HTML; store our findings
                            output.put(url, sb.toString());
                            continue entityLoop; 
                        }
                        sb.append(line);
                    }
                    break; // no more url/html-entities available
                }
            }
        }
    }       
} catch (IOException e) {
    // do something smart
}

// now all your extracted data is stored in "output"
```

There is still room for improvement in the above code. But it should give you an idea on how to get started.